# How to I set the text in a textField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a text field, and I made a reset button for my app. I want the reset button to set the text of the text field to `@""`, or empty string. Which function do I use?

PS I created the IBOutlet, and the textfield is called textFieldX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use setStringValue: and pass @""

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Why did I not see It before?

Comment: It's not always obvious as some methods are so generically reused across AppKit views and controls as to make it difficult to find them. What's harder is that most of those methods are inherited. That means they're documented in an ancestor class. What happens many times is the minor differences get undocumented when the subclass does something slightly different or custom with that method.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try textFieldX.text = @"" ?